# Meteor, Is there any need to create database using "use mydb" programmatically?

Tags: meteor, mongoimport

I have few problems with meteor. Is there any need to create database using "use mydb" programmatically. I didn't used it so far and i'm directly creating collections and applied CRUD operations on them. But, i saw `db.collection.find()` like things few times and when i'm trying to apply on my collection it is showing error like                                `db is not initialized`  how to initialize it.                                                           Here my main problem is, I tried to import some content from `.json` file to my collection. which is possible using database only(i thought). I can import them from shell like this

```
mongoimport --db test --collection mobiles <products.json --jsonArray
```

and how to import them without db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to show some code to see what exactly the issue is.

Meteor uses MongoDB so the schema doesn't need to be strictly created for things to work, like as would be done in MySQL or a traditional SQL type database. You can just insert documents and if the collection doesn't exist, or the database doesn't exist it would be created then without explicitly being created separately.

To import your files you need to import to your meteor database running at port `3002` (if your meteor app is running on port `3000` - meteor app port + 2). Something like this should work, the database is `meteor`

```
mongoimport --db meteor --host localhost:3002 --collection mobiles --jsonArray --file production.json
```

(Not sure about your file structure so i'm assuming its --jsonArray --file production.json). You could check out the docs at http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongoimport/ for more details

So again you wouldn't need to create a database when you do this, using the `--db` argument would load things into `meteor`. If it doesn't exist it would automatically create it as you use it.

Comment: But still when i go into mongo shell i can't find where the collections has stored. I tried use meteor it is showing empty.Where is it stored?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. How do you access the mongo shell? Meteor always stores data in there. What do you use is it `meteor mongo`?

Comment: That's my problem. I used mongo not meteor mango. Thanks for the help and marked as answer.